# Oracle Function or Query to get data for all DB tables?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to get the min and max dates for the data stored in all the database tables and display same along with the table names. I have written below function to do same

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION data_bound(tbl_name IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
  reqdates VARCHAR2;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT concat(min(rec_date),max(rec_date)) from ' || tbl_name INTO reqdates;
  RETURN reqdates;
END;
```

And I am trying to fetch data using below.

```
SELECT table_name, data_bound(table_name) FROM user_tables;
```

But my ***function*** does seems to be working, getting multiple errors. Please can you advise what's wrong here and if there's another better approach.

Comment: Is the function you're calling, `data_retention`, supposed to match the function you're showing, `data_bound`?  Or is there a layer of code missing from your question?

Comment: @JustinCave, updated the question.

Comment: OK.  There are syntax errors compiling your function.  Are those also mistakes in putting the question together?  Or are those in your actual code?

Comment: @JustinCave, sorry those were the mistakes in question.

Comment: OK.  That helps.  Now you say that you're still "getting multiple errors".  Show us the errors you're getting.   Have you tried executing the function with a single hard-coded table name?  Did it produce the results you wanted?  You're building the query assuming there is a column `date` in each table.  `date` is a reserved word so I doubt your tables actually have a column by that name.  Not sure if that is another transcription error though.

Comment: the length part is missing in VARCHAR2 data type for `reqdates` local variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION data_bound(
  tbl_name IN VARCHAR2
) RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
  reqdates VARCHAR2(39);
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT TO_CHAR(min(rec_date), ''YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'')
                         || ''-'' || TO_CHAR(max(rec_date), ''YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'')
                     FROM   ' || DBMS_ASSERT.SIMPLE_SQL_NAME(tbl_name)
    INTO reqdates;
  RETURN reqdates;
END;
/
```

Which, if you have the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (rec_date) AS
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL;
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT data_bound('TABLE_NAME') FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | DATA_BOUND('TABLE_NAME') |
> | --- |
> | 2022-01-01 00:00:00-2022-04-19 18:57:25 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=a6d9868d7f9ee4212c92cf9321a204c6)*

Answer (score 0):

Error 1: data_bound() function is defined. data_retention() function is called

Error 2: tbl_name is taken as input, but not used (t_name is used once)

Error 3: 'from' keyword is missing in the execute immedeate statement

Error 4: 'into' keyword should be placed before 'from tableName'